# Area and Iteration paths are not immediately available

Tags: tfs, area, tfs-workitem

In the code posted for a question of the same title (WorkItemMigrator module by Lars Wilhelmsen), the code appears to either

- creates area/iteration path structures, or
- migrate work items and relink

I tried creating area/iteration path structures, then immediate migrate work items and relink afterwards. The newly created area/iteration path structures seem not to be immediately available and the migration failed.

However, when I then run the code again, migration succeeded.

How can make the newly created area/iteration path structures immediately available, so migration and relinking can proceed successfully immediately afterwards?

Comment: Cross posting on http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsworkitemtracking/thread/9b38ea48-1090-4799-9d8b-d2eea6d699fb. Please let us know if the solution of calling WorkItemStore.RefreshCache() works